# 3D surface with matplotlib is incorrect but contour plot is correct

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a 3D surface with matplotlib for a bunch of math functions. These functions are defined to take in a 1-D numpy array with arbitrary length as input.

When plotted as [contours plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEA0m.png), the plot looks correct.
. However, the [3D surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3u5a.png) plot shows a surface that has been squashed onto a single line. I am using the same values for plotting, so they should be the same, but that's not what I'm getting and I'm very puzzled by this

Please see my code below:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# build the meshgrid
x = np.linspace(bounds[0][0],bounds[0][1])
y = np.linspace(bounds[1][0], bounds[1][1])
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# populate z
z = np.zeros_like(xv)
for row_idx in range(xv.shape[0]):
    for col_idx in range(xv.shape[1]):
        z[row_idx][col_idx] = function(np.array([xv[row_idx][col_idx], yv[row_idx][col_idx]]))

# plot 3D surface
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')

# plot a contour
ax.contourf(x, y, z, cmap='viridis')
plt.show()

# function that I'm plotting -> bowl shaped for 2D x
def function(x):
    return sum(x**2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have this wrong but if you are just wanting the surface mesh you need to plot the gridded data as opposed to the linear one so just change this line:

```py
ax.plot_surface(xv, yv, z, cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
```

Note I'm using `xv`, `yv` instead of `X`,`Y`.

Here is my output. [image]

Comment: Ohh I see now. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: No problem :) These things always slip through